# How do I set the proper path to Android Studio in Ionic/Capacitor?

Tags: linux, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm working through an Ionic/React getting-started, on my Linux Mint box.

[Building an Ionic application using React](https://itnext.io/building-an-ionic-application-using-react-61dc60c59e7b)

The first steps went well enough, but when I get to **Deploying your application to iOS and Android** Step 5, I get errors.

The instructions:

```
Open your project in Android Studio using the following command:

    npx cap open android
```

First I got pathing errors:

```
events.js:174
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: spawn /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh 
ENOENT
```

That seemed simple enough. That's not where android studio is installed on my machine.

I did some googling around, and some grepping in node_modules, and discovered the "androidStudioPath" setting. I tried adding it to my project's capacitor.config.json file, and it made no difference. So I looked at the code a bit more carefully, and then added it in a "linux" object:

```
{
    "appId": "us.jdege.mytestapp",
    "appName": "mytestapp",
    "bundledWebRuntime": false,
    "npmClient": "npm",
    "webDir": "build",
    "linux": {
        "androidStudioPath": "/var/.../studio.sh"
    }
}
```

From all I can tell, this is the right setting, and I'm setting the right path. But it's being ignored.

```
jdege@linux-2016 ~/react-projects/mytestapp $ npx cap open android
[info] Opening Android project at /home/jdege/react-projects/mytestapp/android
events.js:174
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: spawn /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

How do I set the proper path to Android Studio in Ionic/Capacitor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the source, Luke!

The proper setting is "linuxAndroidStudioPath".

In ./node_modules/@capacitor/cli/dist/android/open.js, you'll find:

```
common_1.logError('Unable to launch Android Studio. You must configure "linuxAndroidStudioPath" ' +
'in your capacitor.config.json to point to the location of studio.sh, using JavaScript-escaped paths:\n' +
'Example:\n' +
'{\n' +
'  "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"\n' +
'}');
```

So while in ./capacitor.config.json this doesn't work:

```
{
    ...
    "androidStudioPath": "/var/.../studio.sh"
}
```

And this doesn't work:

```
{
    ...
    "linux": {
        "androidStudioPath": "/var/.../studio.sh"
    }
}
```

This does:

```
{
    ...
    "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/var/.../studio.sh"
}
```

Comment: But how can I configure for multiple developers which uses different paths depending on its OS? This file is shared, so it can be committed by each developer. 

Using `CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH` didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I use **JetBrains Toolbox** to manage my Android Studio on my **macOS**

to use `npx cap open android` I had to export the Android Studio path as follow:

```
export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH="/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/201.7199119/Android Studio.app"
```